# This NSURL request compiles, but doesn't work as expected. What am I missing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, boolean, nsurl

I'm currently taking a course in iOS development. I've created a basic web browser that can handle an URL that's entered and will add "http://" if the user doesn't add it. With the code below, the user enters text in `textField`, the app loads a webpage.

I've been tasked with treating `textField` entries with spaces as Google searches. When I run my app, it loads webpages, but Google searches don't work. I'm stumped as to why, but I know I can rest assured it's something I did wrong. The question is what?

Here are the properties:

```
// Properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSearchTerm;
```

Here's `BOOL` I wrote to test if `textField` is an URL or a search term:

```
// Test to determine whether textField.text is a searchTerm
- (BOOL)isSearchTerm:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *textInURLBar = textField.text;
    NSRange whiteSpaceRange = [textInURLBar rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if (whiteSpaceRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // Do a test of textField to see if it's a webpage or a search term
    if (self.isSearchTerm == YES) {
        // Homework: write code to searchGoogle, see method below
        [self searchGoogle:textField];
    } else {
        // isSearchTerm == NO, so treat as an URL
        NSString *URLString = textField.text;
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

        // User enters incomplete URL
        if (!URL.scheme) {
            // if the user didn't enter http:// or https://
            URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URLString]];
        }

        // User enters complete URL
        if (URL) {
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Code to search Google:

```
- (void)searchGoogle:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSString *URLString = textField.text;
    NSRange spaces = [URLString rangeOfString:@" "];
    NSString *searchTerm = [URLString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:spaces withString:@"+"];
    // Google search query is http://www.google.com/search?q=
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@", searchTerm]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Log your `searchGoogle` method to see if its being called correctly first off all.  This will help you narrow down the issue `NSLog(@"Is Google Search");` place this in your `- (void)searchGoogle:(UITextField *)textField {` method

Comment: I replaced `[self searchGoogle:textField]` with `NSLog(@"Is Google Search")` in `textFieldShouldReturn:textField` and nothing shows up in the console. It will return a properly formatted URL in the textField, so I figured it worked.

Nothing shows up in console when I put `NSLog(@"Is Google Search")` in `- (void)searchGoogle:(UITextField *)textField`, either.

Comment: If you're not seeing any log statements, then it might not be running this routine at all (e.g. did you perhaps neglect to specify the delegate for the textfield). But if this routine is running, then set a breakpoint in here and single step through the routine to figure out where its going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I got it to work. I took out the `BOOL` and `googleSearch` functions and dumped everything in `textFieldShouldReturn`.

Rather than have a bunch of code dumped into `textFieldShouldReturn`, I'd like to break this up into more re-usable code (that works). While it works, I think it's ugly.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *URLString = textField.text;

    // This is if it's a normal request
    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

        // User enters incomplete URL
        if (!URL.scheme) {
            // if the user didn't enter http:// or https://
            URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", URLString]];
        }

        // User enters complete URL
        if (URL) {
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        }
    }

    // This handles a space in the textField.text
    if ([URLString rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"there's a space in the request");
        URLString = [URLString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
        NSLog(@"The new URLString is %@", URLString);
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
        // User enters incomplete URL
        if (!URL.scheme) {
            // if the user didn't enter http:// or https://
            URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com/search?q=%@", URLString]];
        }

        // User enters complete URL
        if (URL) {
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [self.webView loadRequest:request];
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to replace spaces with `+`, you're currently doing that for the first occurrence only. You might want to do that for all occurrences. Thus, instead of `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`, you might use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`.

Alternatively, you might want to percent escape the input (to handle not only spaces, but other reserved characters, too. Web browsers tend to do that for you, but when creating a request yourself, you have to do this manually in your code. So, at the very least you could create new string using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` (in lieu of `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`).

Technically, you might want to refine the google logic further (do percent escaping, replacing spaces with `+` characters, but properly percent escape characters that the above will not) you need to precent escape more characters than `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will do on its own), so you would do the following percent escaping on the values that you add to the google query (but not to the URL itself):

```
- (NSString *)percentEscapeString:(NSString *)string
{ 
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

Comment: Where does `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` go?

Comment: Where you're currently doing `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`.

Comment: Actually, you really want to do this regardless of whether its a google search or not.

Comment: Thank you! I think that will fix a problem I'd have a little further down the line. Based on jsa986's suggestion I added some `NSLog` statements to see if things are getting called...and nothing's showing up in console. I think I've got a problem before I get to `searchGoogle`.

Comment: I think I'm going to revert back to a prior copy on Github and try to refactor it so it's cleaner, less code, etc. and incorporate your `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString` suggestion.  It's still not working, but I think I'm trying to make something simple too complex.